# Copy from worksheet to worksheet when worksheets names are the same

Tags: excel, vba, loops, copy-paste, worksheet

I have two workbooks with worksheets (having the same names). I would like copy and paste specific cells from one worksheet to another if the name of worksheets are the same.

I tried to compare name of worksheets with array based on names from another workbook but stack when comes to comparison

```vb
Sub check()
    Dim xArray, i
    Dim x As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\user\Desktop\xxx.xlsx", False)


    With x
    ReDim xArray(1 To Sheets.Count)
    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
        xArray(i) = x.Sheets(i).Name
Debug.Print xArray(i)
    Next
    End With
x.Close (False)

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name = xArray Then
    ' copy for each worksheet define in xArray xxx.xlsx file, range A1,B4,D5:G5
    ' and paste to worksheet with the same name in this open workbook

End Sub
```

Thanks for any help !

Comment: Untested but for a match you could try `if isnumeric(application.match(ws.name,xarray,0)) then`.

Comment: Works fine, thank you ! Could you help me define the rest of code concerning copy and pasting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an Error handler to test if the sheet exists.

```
Sub check()
    Dim wb As Workbook, SouceWorksheet As Worksheet, TargetWorksheet As Worksheet
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\user\Desktop\xxx.xlsx", False)

    For Each SouceWorksheet In wb.Worksheets
        On Error Resume Next
        Set TargetWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SouceWorksheet.Name)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not TargetWorksheet Is Nothing Then
            SouceWorksheet.Range("A1").Copy TargetWorksheet.Range("A1")
            SouceWorksheet.Range("B4").Copy TargetWorksheet.Range("B4")
            SouceWorksheet.Range("D5:G5").Copy TargetWorksheet.Range("D5:G5")
        End If
    Next
    wb.Close False
End Sub
```

Comment: Brillant ! Can you add a criteria that exclude one worksheet from macro?

Comment: Just wrap everything inside the loop in an if statement.

Comment: could you help me modified the macro for copy and pasting cells that are merge or not.

Answer (score 0):

for this functionality , you don't need to create array , it can be done easily with simple logic mentioned below.Also you can customize or replace your workbook and worksheet name and your copy-paste range in the below code.

```
Sub so()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks("Book1.xlsx")
Set wb1 = Workbooks("Book2.xlsx")
Dim wk As Worksheet
Set wk = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim wm As Worksheet
Set wm = wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1")

If (wk.Name = wm.Name) Then
        Dim TR As Integer
        TR = wk.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        wk.Range("A1:A" & TR).Copy wm.Range("A1")
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

       End If

End Sub
```